# Increasing execution time of query in recordset (CursorLocation )

Tags: vb6, recordset

I am using below code to retrieve data from table.
After that i am binding resultant data to grid.
Problem is with speed.This query taking almost 2 to 3 minute to execute wherease from backend it takes 30 to  40 seconds.

-----------Current Code ------------------

```
rs.ActiveConnection = con //con is connection
con.Errors.Clear
rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.StayInSync = True
On Error Resume Next
rs.Open strCmd //strCmd is query
```

------- Alternate solution I tried using Client ---------------

```
rs.ActiveConnection = con //con is connection
con.Errors.Clear
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rs.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
rs.StayInSync = True
On Error Resume Next
rs.Open strCmd //strCmd is query
```

/// Result : Same speed

--------Alternate solution using Execute rather than Open recodset ---------------

```
com.ActiveConnection = con //con is connection
com.CommandType = adCmdText
com.CommandTimeout = 500
com.CommandText = strCmd //strCmd is query
con.Errors.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set rs= com.Execute()
```

//Result :Speed is fast but when I try to update value in grid it is showing bellow error :

> "Run-time error '3251': Current Recordset does not support
>   updating.This may be a limitation of the provider,or of the selected
>   locktype."

---

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably your table(s) setup / query, and not your connection that's causing the issues.

Make sure that every field listed in the WHERE, JOIN, & ORDER BY clauses are indexed.

Reevaluate any derived fields you are creating. I saw a query the other day that combined 2 text fields and then sorted on that new, -unindexed-, field.

If you post your query and your table structure, it will give me a better idea.